# Cannot empty iCloud trash folder

Tags: icloud, high-sierra, folders, trash

I've had this infuriating problem for quite some time now, where I can't empty my Trash. More specifically, every time I empty it, there's a folder called *temp(1)* that keeps reappearing in there after a while. I managed to determine this folder comes from iCloud (specifically the *.trash* folder under the iCloud library folder). I have no idea how all that information got in there (I had no idea iCloud has its own trash folder), but it's been there for a while apparently.

[image: iCloud trash folder]
[image: folder in iCloud web interface]

I've tried everything I could think of to remedy this:

- delete the .trash folder from the console
- rename it
- move it to other iCloud tracked folder (like Desktop)
- delete it using the iCloud web interface
- delete it from my iPhone

No matter what I do, it keeps reappearing. It's driving me insane. My guess is that there's some server side error and the iCloud storage server can't remove this folder, so that's why it keeps getting resurrected. Any idea what I can do in this case?

Comment: Just a thought, what if you sign out of iCloud, reboot, empty the trash and sign back in. Does it then return?

Comment: Hi Steve, yes the folder would keep reappearing during the sync with iCloud drive servers, as it would not be removed from there. I've tried removing it from the web interface (using the "Delete all" option, see pic from main description) but it's not working (folder will reappear after a while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this was happening. I have a Windows box which I completely forgot I installed iCloud on. For some reason, that temp folder would not get deleted on the Windows machine, and it was re-uploaded to iCloud every night. That's why it was re-appearing on the other devices.

After deleting the folder from the Windows machine, the issue stopped happening. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the hidden .Trash folder on the PC in the iCloud Drive folder in my Windows User Profile folder, for some reason neither deleting within iCloud nor Emptying the trash on my Mac sync'd as such on Windows thus they stayed in .trash hidden folder in Windows. I  guess when iCloud on the PC sync'd it put them back in iCloud.